# Meteortoys not working

Tags: javascript, debugging, meteor

I'm using the package `meteortoys:allthings` in my project but the tools won't shop up in my application, even if I press "ctrl+M"

I have the following system:
Meteor 1.3.2.4
Chrome 50
Linux Mint 17